# open multiple browser windows side by side using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding.

I am trying to open two browser windows side by side by clicking a button.

a. window a will be 80% and aligned to top right
b. window b will be 20% and aligned to the left.

Both windows will be open with a single button. This is what I have so far I would like to change the 2nd popover to open at width*0.8
and also find a way to overide the browser popup blocker

```
<html>

<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>
<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup1(url)
{
 params1  = 'width='+screen.width/100*80;
 params1 += ', height='+screen.height;
 params1 += ', top=0, left=0'
 params1 += ', fullscreen=yes';

 newwin=window.open("https://thespark.ai",'windowname4', params1);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
function popup2(url)
{
 params2  = 'width='+screen.width/100*20;
 params2 += ', height='+screen.height;
 params2 += ', top=0,left='+screen.width/100*80;
 params2 += ', fullscreen=yes';

 newwin=window.open("https://dribbble.com",'windowname5', params2);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
// -->
</script>

<a href="javascript: void(0)"
   onclick="popup1(); popup2()">Fullscreen popup window</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't resize a window from inside a website.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski You can open a new window and set its location on the screen with `window.open()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hey scott thanks fro the comment i am using window open and that is partialy working : my two problems are : 1. i want to change the width variable to be in precentage of the screen so the code would have a get screen width and then the width value of the popup would be in %.  2.opening both popups at the same time for some reason you have to press the button twice to do this

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i am ok with launching two new windows as the code suggests my 2 problems are opening the at the same time and resizing them as a % of the screen not as a fixed value .

Comment: get screen width and multiple times `0.8` to get 80%

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i updated the code in my question - how can i replace the 2nd popup location to be located at 80% of screen width

Comment: @ScottMarcus _"You can open a new window and set its location on the screen with window.open()"_ - in browsers that still give the user very little control, perhaps. My browser is configured to never open any "popups" with custom dimensions to begin with, any `window.open` call with _whatever_ parameters, will only open a new, full-sized _tab_. And forget about "moving" those around ...

Comment: You could awaken a decades old technique of using a [frameset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset). No need to open two windows.

Comment: `'left='+screen.width/100*20;`

Comment: `find a way to override the browser popup blocker` cannot be done. Also, on my system popups are opening with the correct size, but the location cannot be changed. Maybe we are trying to fix an existing problem. Why do you want to open anything with a popup anyway? Nobody does this anymore.

Comment: Popup blockers exist because popups are annoying. You should solve this differently.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Or use an `iframe` which isn't considered the atrocity that the `frameset` is.

Comment: Yes I have prepared an iframe example below, since frameset is deprecated. Last time I used a frameset was 1998.

Comment: maybe i am approaching this wrong here is my goal we are using powerbi and an external form power bi doesnt have forms so my goal is to show them side by side the function is intended to open another instance of power bi at 0.8 + the form url at 0.2 size

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Use iframe tags

The iframe tag allows you to show a website inside another. Your HTML should have two iframe tags next to each other simply with `width:20%` and `width:80%`, respectively.

Be aware of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) same-origin policy rules.

See documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { height: 100%; }

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0 none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe.left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

iframe.right {
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<iframe class="left" scrolling="no" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/800"></iframe>
<iframe class="right" scrolling="no" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/so/1200/800"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```